Can SSRS Subscription Reconciliation Process be Disabled
Working a proof of concept to attempt to hack sql jobs created by ssrs to run report subscription schedules. The ssrs api is called to create subscriptions to various reports. The scheduling capabilities of ssrs are not as full featured as the sql server jobs allow, so an attempt is made to update the job after its creation. This works as planned, however, on some interval thereafter, some service runs and performs a subscription reconciliation, leaving all "hacked" jobs reverted back to a different state. I can see that the last modified date is updated as a batch, so the assumption is that ssrs is reconciling. There are no documents on this caveat. Does anyone have any info about this process and if there is maybe some arcane web.config entry or other system setting that can turn this service off?


My goal is to enable a subscription schedule for "Last Day of Month" and for every X months.

I wouldn't change the jobs.  Instead run the jobs from another job on whatever schedule you want using sp_startjob.  Alternatively run the subscription with the ReportServer.dbo.AddEvent stored procedure.  See eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67830098/how-do-execute-an-ssrs-report-with-a-parameter-from-within-a-cursor-driven-sql-s

Solutions here are great, however, we would require a new custom thread pool service to run all reports and tend to the schedules:). Think it may be easier just to turn "End of Month" into "Start of Month" since it is not mission critical a few seconds won't matter, just the timestamp on teh report will be off and wonky..

Wait, I think I understand. If another job is created to run the AddEvent at the desired interval and simply not call the API altogether, that might be a solution for the not supported subscription schedules. WOW thanks.
